# How do I execute shell commands through eggPlant on Windows?

Tags: windows, shell, automation, adb, eggplant

I am working on test automation for an Android app. I am currently using eggPlant for Android. 
Summary of my present situation:

- I am successfully running tests on one Android device, that runs eggOn and is connected to eggPlant Functional
- eggPlant Functional is being run on a Windows 7 Pro (SP1, 64-bit) machine.
- I have about 50 manual functional tests that presently need automation; many of which *will* require some adb shell scripting alongside eggPlant automation.

Documentation on eggPlant websites ([1](http://docs.testplant.com/?q=content/system-interaction) and [2](http://docs.testplant.com/?q=content/adb-command-support)) talks about the ability in eggPlant to run commands on the local shell. The examples (at the time of writing) are for Mac. I tried various modifications to these examples to make them run on Windows, such as:

e.g. 1

```
put shell("dir")
```

e.g. 2

```
set the shellCommand to "ShellExecute"
shell "example.bat" //where example.bat contains "dir"
```

e.g. 3

```
shell "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c dir"
```

My ultimate objective is to run adb commands off the Windows shell. But the problems I am facing are:

- Silent failure with no "cause" whatsoever
- No way to observe the output of the commands

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working in conjunction with TestPlant Support.

- Windows + eggPlant does not have the ability to read console output. You need to dump the output to a file and then read it back.
- First make a handler (or in plain words, function) as follows.
- Modify the path `sdkPath` according to your Windows system.

In this example I want to run `adb shell "df | grep data  | awk '{print $4}'"` which will basically print out the free space in the `/data` folder of my Android Device.

Since my code has quotes, I have to enclose the code within `<<>>` .

```
to adb
    set command to <<shell "df | grep data  | awk '{print $4}'">>
    put "D:\adt-bundle\sdk\platform-tools" into sdkPath 
    set cmd to " /c " && sdkPath & "\adb.exe" && command && " > C:\adbOutput.txt"
    put cmd
    shell "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe", cmd
end adb
```

The value of the variable `cmd` expands to `/c  D:\adt-bundle\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe shell "df | grep data  | awk '{print $4}'"  > C:\adbOutput.txt`.

Ultimately what gets executed is equivalent to

```
cmd /c D:\adt-bundle\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe shell "df | grep data  | awk '{print $4}'"  > C:\adbOutput.txt
```

If I want to make the `adb` handler accept parameters,  I'd add a `Params cmd` line to the `adb` handler, obviously.

Comment: can you please let me know how to redirect the output of adb command to a variable and log the same

Comment: @manju that's really a different question. Can you post it as a question? I don't have eggPlant installed anymore, but I can try to answer it.
EDIT: It's not really a different question, it's the same :) 

Unfortunately I don't have eggPlant installed. But I believe the output gets stored into a variable called `the result`? Does that work for you?

Comment: @Vish Unfortunately, no. ["The shell command and function both set the result to the exit code of the command that ran,"](http://docs.testplant.com/ePF/SenseTalk/stk-system-interaction.htm), most likely `0`.